# access multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

This is sort of a follow up to my last question. Im trying to access the data of a multidimensional array so as to insert into a database. Ive been looking all over the forums as well as trying different things on my own but cant find anything that works. Here is what the array looks like:

```
 $_POST[] = array[stake](
    'stakeholder1' => array(
        'partner'=> 'partner',
        'meet'=> 'meet'
    ),
    'stakeholder2' => array(
        'partner'=> 'partner',
        'agreement'=> 'agreement',
        'train'=> 'train',
        'meet'=> 'meet'
    ),
);
```

I'm trying to do somthing like ( `UPDATE list WHERE stakeholder = "stakeholder1" SET partner =1, meet =1` ) depending on which stakeholder/choices were selected (theres four different options). Thanks,

Comment: What is your database table schema? I'm assuming something like:
`stakeholder = string, partner = binary(1), agreement = binary(1), train = binary(1), meet = binary(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = '';
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $query .= "UPDATE list WHERE stakeholder = '$k' SET " . implode(" = 1," $v) . ",";
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -2); //Get rid of the final comma
```

This should give you something like what you are looking for, if I understand your database schema correctly.

Comment: Yeah thats it. This is what the my input name looks like: name ="stake[$stakeid][$options]". When I echo $k it returns "stake" and not "stakeholder1" for example...like it is one level up?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case according to the array you posted in your original post. Can you update the original post to include a print_r($_POST) so I can see the actual array format?

Comment: Ok I put the corrected array up. Forgot to add the array name. I figured it out too; I just add [stake] after $_POST in the foreach statement. Thanks, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

This one will set 1 for checked options, and 0 for unchecked options (otherwise you will miss some data updates).

```
$optionsList = array('partner', 'agreement', 'train', 'meet');
$stakeHolders = array('stakeholder1', 'stakeholder2', ...);

foreach($stakeHolders as $stakeHolder)
{
  $selectedOptions = $_POST[$stakeHolder];

  $arInsert = array();
  foreach($optionsList as $option)
    $arInsert[] = '`'.$option.'` = '.intval(isset($selectedOptions[$option]));

  $sql = "UPDATE list
    SET ".implode(", ", $arInsert)."
    WHERE stakeholder = '".mysql_real_escape_string($stakeHolder)."'";

  // TODO: execute $sql (mysql_query(), or PDO call,
  // or any wrapper you use for DB)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDO, you could do something like:

```
foreach($_POST as $stakeholder => $data) {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE `list` SET `' . implode('` = 1, `', array_keys($data)) . '` = 1 WHERE stakeholder = ?');
    $sth->execute(array($stakeholder));
}
```

Be sure to sanitize the user input (keys of the data...).

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($main_array as $key => $sub_array) {

  $sql = 'UPDATE list 
          WHERE stakeholder = "{$key}"
          SET ';

  $sets = array();

  foreach($sub_array as $column_value)
     $sets[] = $column_value." = 1";

  $sql = $sql.implode(',', $sets);


}
```

Comment: SQL injection fail and syntax fail. What if you got `stakeholder1' or '1' = '1` as a key?

Comment: Then there is the fact that this will not pass syntax.

Comment: And when it was edited, it was testing for stakeholder = '{$key}' (meaning that $key would be a literal).

Comment: The original author said nothing about sanitizing the incoming data.

Comment: Apolgoies. I added that comment before the page showed your first comment, so I retract that statement